# How can I calculate a sliding window over an array in powershell?

Tags: powershell

Given an array `$arr = 1,2,3,4`, I want to create a new array with a sliding window of the value. My specific need is for a window of size 2, so the result is `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`, but would like to know if there is a generic solution.

My ultimate need is to calculate the difference between consecutive elements, to get `[1,1,1,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are very tricky. See generic solution to sliding window and your ultimate need below:

```
$arr = 1,2,3,4
#create window, notice comma (,)
$result = 1..($arr.Length-1) | % { ,($arr[$_-1], $arr[$_]) }

#show elements
"[0][0]=$($result[0][0])"
"[0][1]=$($result[0][1])"

#ultimate need
1..($arr.Length-1) | % { $arr[$_]-$arr[$_-1] }
```

Take a look at this fragment from about_Arrays documentation:

> You can also get the members of an array by typing a comma (,) before
>   the value that is piped to the Get-Member cmdlet. The comma makes the 
>   array the second item in an array of arrays. Windows PowerShell pipes
>   the arrays one at a time and Get-Member returns the members of the
>   array.
>
> ,$a | Get-Member
>
> ,(1,2,3) | Get-Member

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply calculate a new array with the differences between the consecutive elements, if that's what you're actually after?

```
$diff = @(for ($i=0; $i -lt $arr.Count-1; $i++) {
  $arr[$i+1] - $arr[$i]
})
```

The resulting array would be `[1,1,1]`, though, as the last element of `$arr` doesn't have a neighboring element to be compared to.