# Does PowerShell have a "window" function?

Tags: powershell, functional-programming, pipeline

I was looking for a "window" function like F#'s `Seq.windowed` or the Reactive extensions [`Window`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/bnaya/2011/12/31/rx-window/). It looks like it would be provided by the likes of `Select-Object` (which already has take / skip functionality), but it is not.

If nothing is readily available, any ideas on implementing "window" without unnecessary procedural looping?

I'm looking for something that works with the PowerShell pipeline nicely.

Comment: Not something readily available in PowerShell, but [this might prove useful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566936/how-can-i-calculate-a-sliding-window-over-an-array-in-powershell)? Also, what do you mean by "works with the PowerShell pipeline nicely"? Can you show/describe what kind of behavior you expect with a sample input/output?

Comment: `function window { param($size) begin { $array = [object[]]::new($size); $i = 0 } process { if($i -lt $size) { $array[$i++] = $_; if ($i -eq $size) { ,@($array) } } else { ,@(($array = @($array | select -skip 1; ,$_))) } } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some kind of queue to accumulate and rotate enough previous pipeline items:

```
function Window {
    param($Size)
    begin {
        $Queue = [Collections.Queue]::new($Size)
    }
    process {
        $Queue.Enqueue($_)
        if($Queue.Count -eq $Size) {
            @(
                ,$Queue.ToArray()
                [void]$Queue.Dequeue()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
1..10 | Window 4 | Window 3 | Format-Custom -Expand CoreOnly
```

Comment: Neat. ( `$Queue = New-Object -TypeName "Collections.Queue" $Size` for anyone else using PSv4 )

Comment: Love this! Great job.

Comment: Do I strictly need a queue? What about a local array that I add to, check Count, and reset? Any limitations there?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean It is definitely possible to implement this with [local array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508855/does-powershell-have-a-window-function#comment70226596_41508855), but then you need to write your own code for FIFO rotation, while with `Queue` you just `Enqueue` and `Dequeue`.

Comment: What exactly is happening inside that if/count block? Is that some fancy way to return the current window and dequeue the first item without assigning some intermediate value holder? Would a try...finally work?

Comment: Or is part of that syntax to avoid PowerShell unrolling the... output?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean It is more or less equivalent to `$Temp = $Queue.ToArray(); [void]$Queue.Dequeue(); ,$Temp`. It will `Dequeue` first queue item before writing array to pipeline, but not use temporary variable to store array. The part to prevent unrolling is comma `,` only.

Comment: That comma is awkward, is that documented? Is there any other syntax for that?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean *is that documented?* Yes, [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators): **, Comma operator** As a unary operator, the comma creates an array with one member. Place the comma before the member. *Is there any other syntax for that?* Any other way to create collection with one element will do. And for advanced functions `$PSCmdlet.WriteObject` does not enumerate collections, unless explicitly asked for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in as far as I know. PowerShell's handling of the pipeline and in particular its strong insistence on unrolling enumerables makes it a bit difficult to be able to just write a function to pipe into, but as a general expression:

```
$a = 1..10  # an array contain 1 through 10
$w = 4      # window size of 4

0..($a.Length-$w) | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $a[$_..($_+$w-1)]
}
```

That does process arrays that are the window you want. It's easier to see like this:

```
0..($a.Length-$w) | ForEach-Object -Process {
    "This is my window: $($a[$_..($_+$w-1)])"
}
```

The thing is, if you tried to do the above this way:

```
0..($a.Length-$w) | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $a[$_..($_+$w-1)]
} | ForEach-Object -Process {
    "This is my window: $_"
}
```

You'd be very disappointed as the "window" array was unrolled before being piped into `ForEach-Object`; a problem you'd have with any pipeline function you wrote to handle this as well.

There's no way to compensate for it within the function, you'd have to take care to use it inside the `ForEach-Object` block because even on assignment:

```
$myWindows = 0..($a.Length-$w) | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $a[$_..($_+$w-1)]
}
```

It would be unrolled.

So then you would need something like:

```
0..($a.Length-$w) | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    $myWindows = @()
} -Process {
    $myWindows += @(,$a[$_..($_+$w-1)])
}
```

Which you could then use like:

```
$myWindows | ForEach-Object -Process {
    "This is my window: $_"
}
```

Comment: *There's no way to compensate for it within the function* Really? Does that not work for you: `$myWindows = @(0..($a.Length-$w) | % { ,$a[$_..($_+$w-1)] })`?

Comment: @PetSerAl I have that as an example (second the last code block). What I mean is that if you wanted to be able to pipe an existing array into something and process a window (like `$a | Select-Window`) you cannot, because the function will receive a single item at a time, so it can't access the other array elements. The caller has to compensate: `,$a | Select-Window`.

Comment: `0..($a.Length-$w) | % { ,$a[$_..($_+$w-1)] } | % { "Single array at time: $_" }`

Comment: @PetSerAl my point still stands though. If you try to write a function that takes an array of something via the pipeline, there's nothing you can do in the function that allows the caller to avoid re-embedding their array inside another (aside from hardcoding variable names that are defined outside the function, which still doesn't give you the piping behavior you'd expect).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but `1..10 | window 4 | % { "$_" }`. Look, [question comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508855/does-powershell-have-a-window-function/41509555?noredirect=1#comment70226596_41508855) for `window`.

Comment: @PetSerAl ah I see what you mean now; you're _rebuilding_ the array item by item. That's quite nice, you should really post an answer.

Comment: None of your examples can _stream_ input from the pipeline though, they have to have access to the entire array (the only way you can ask for Length), right?

Comment: @AnthonyMastrean correct, PetSerAl came up with a brilliant solution that does work the way you want though. I recommend his answer.

Comment: Just wanted to be sure, thanks for your disassembly of the problem though!